# how to sort a matrix in matlab

Tags: sorting

I have matrix like=

1 10 2 0  1 5  9 7  50

5 7 13 87 3 10 9 54 90

60 2 25 16 0 1  0 25  3

but after sorting the matrix will look like

0  1  1  2  5   7   9  10  50

3  5  7  9  10  13  54 87  94

0  0  1  2  3   16  25 25  60

But i am unable to do this in MATLAB.It would be great if anyone help me.

Comment: Maybe the [sort](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) function?

Comment: Yes i have tried with sort function but the output is not same as what i need.need help

Answer (score 1):

$\mathtt{help\,\ sort}$:

> SORT(X,DIM) sorts along the dimension DIM.

Comment: @user1551-can you please specify for my above example what is the value of DIM?

Comment: @user1679276 Why don't you just type "help sort" in Matlab and see what the documentation says?

Comment: Better yet, experiment with a simpler case.